# Get updated image in flex image control after changing source not name of file(image)?

Tags: apache-flex

I am changing image through flex every time i change it saved into server directory with same name(which i am referring to show). So when i refresh my page my browser didn't send new request to server since it's already in request.so didn't getting new image.Tip:- when i clear browser history it will come with new image

Comment: This is a browser caching issue not really a flex issue if I understand it correct. What you should do is to make sure you load a non cached image all the time, like   "..server_url/image.png?"+UIDUtil.createUID();

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding an additional time-stamp to the image source each time u make a new request, which would make the request look different for the browser.

Example :

```
var src:String = "image.png";
src = src  + "?" + new Date().getTime().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you're refreshing the browser, then I assume that your embedded SWF file will also need to be refreshed.

When you embed your SWF, you need to add a parameter that would be random across all time (i.e. datetime stamp, etc.)

```
var mySWF = "swf/YourEmbeddedFlashFile.swf?guid=" + rnd();
```

and declare a js function:

```
function rnd() 
{
  return String((new Date()).getTime()).replace(/\D/gi, '')
}
```